# I have a tricky grep issue involving special characters

Tags: regex, linux, grep

If I have a file named test with 1 line of text: `\<.abc`

and do a `grep '\<abc' test`

why do I get a result?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when working with regular expressions if you want to match a literal backslash character it needs to be escaped, so you should see the correct behavior if you use `grep '\\<abc' test`.

As for what the `\<` is actually doing in the regular expression, this is from the grep man page:

```
   The symbols \< and \>  respectively  match  the  empty  string  at  the
   beginning and end of a word.
```